# How do I downgrade USB 2.0 to USB 1.1 in windows 10

Tags: usb

Is there any way to downgrade the USB 2.0 port to work as USB1.1 in windows 10? I understand USB2.0 is backward compatible, But I want the port to work as OHCI port.

I tried disabling the drivers, then USB devices are not detected. I tried Installing 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller (Legacy) , But I cannot see this in device manager.

Please help.

Comment: I'm struggling with the rationale for this. What is wrong with using the USB 2 port?

Comment: I want the USB 2.0 device connected to be accessed in Virtual box as USB1.1

Comment: When I use a USB1.1 hub and USB2 device is connected to the hub, everything is working fine. But I don't want an USB hub to be connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller" is not an USB but a Firewire driver. The "OHCI" is unfortunately used in both USB and Firewire worlds.

When USB 2.0 was introduced, the EHCI USB 2.0 controllers frequently included "companion controller" hardware that was used to handle USB 1.1. But this was just a compatibility workaround for OSs that did not have EHCI drivers built-in: there was no inherent reason why an EHCI driver could not handle USB 1.1 speeds too.

By now, the EHCI driver support in OSs, even at OS installation time, is ubiquitous enough that the companion controllers are being left out of the hardware. In fact, even the EHCI is getting left out in modern systems: most new systems are XHCI-only.

Comment: So we can conclude like, we cannot downgrade USB2.0 to USB1.1 in windows 10?

Comment: "in Windows 10" - it's not depending on the OS, but the hardware. Your hardware probably doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on hardware of your computer.

There are several kinds of USB controllers.

One is provided on old Intel machines, and uses a combination of EHCI (USB 2.0 HS mode) and (Intel-proprietary) UHCI, which supported FS and LS modes.

The other one is usually found in non-Intel machines, where the HS mode is provided by the same open EHCI hardware, but the LS/FS modes are implemented as OHCI controller.

The extra distinction comes with USB 3.0 and xHCI controller. Earlier implementations of xHCI didn't support USB 2.0 modes, so these modes were supported with either type-one or type-two USB 2.0 combinations, aka "companion controllers".

On machines with the first three types of hardware it was sufficient to disable the EHCI driver in Device Manager. Then the ports would behave as USB 1.1 ports, converting HS devices into FS devices. Restoring full HS functionality was as easy as enabling EHCI driver back.

In recent years a progress was made in xHCI hardware, so Intel-based machines don't have the "companion" [EHCI/UHCI hardware anymore](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ehci-removal-6th-gen-core-pch-technical-paper.pdf), and all USB modes are handled by recent unified Microsoft xHCI driver, about since 2016. I don't know of any way to disable USB 2.0 functionality and resort to USB 1.1 mode.

You can't change the USB HS host behavior by degrading signals in attempt to "force" backward compatibility, [see this explanation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/311591/117785). If you need USB 1.1 operations only, you can use an old USB 1.1 hub. Then all downstream HS devices will connect in FS mode.